# Parsing a large XML file with SAX & XPATH

Tags: php, xml, parsing, sax

I have the below code wich is parsing a xml file an extract a child info based on another child value.
The code works well, but my xml file has over 200mb and when i try to parse and get several data`s the site is loading in about 4 mins or more :(

```
$dom    = new DOMDocument();
$xpath  = new DOMXPath($dom);
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('http://www.bookingassist.ro/test/HotelsPro.xml');
while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'Hotel') {
        $node = $dom->importNode($reader->expand(), true);
        $dom->appendChild($node);
        $h1name = $xpath->evaluate('string(/Hotel[HotelCode = "'.$hotelCodes[0].'"]/HotelName)', $node);
        $dom->removeChild($node);
        if ($h1name) {
         $reader->close();
         break;
        }
    }
}
```

How can i parse this document to retrieve the data faster. As i have searched over internet SAX will do the thing but i don`t have any idea of how to use it.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: That example is not SAX, it uses XMLReader and DOM - different APIs

Answer (score 4):

The DOM parser loads the data into memory. The SAX parser is a stream parser which I've found to be very fast and efficient.

The challenge with the SAX parser is that you need to know the tag names and capture data as you stream through the XML.

**You need to setup three functions to use a SAX parser...**

1. The first function which is triggered by the start element of the XML (opening tag). This function returns the name of the opening tag and any attributes.

   function startElement($xml_parser, $name, $attributes)
2. The second function which is triggered by the end element of the XML (closing tag). Only the name of the closing tag is returned in this function.

   function endElement($xml_parser, $name)
3. Finally, the third function to handle the character data which is streaming between the start and end elements(opening and closing tags).

   function characterData($xml_parser, $data)

You will need to put your logic into these three functions to do the work, storing any information you need on the fly. Use the CASE function to do different things when you come to different opening or closing tags.

Once you have your functions, you can then initialise the parser...
You must use the function names in the **xml_set_element_handler** and the **xml_set_character_data_handler** options.

```
        //Initialise SAX parser
$xml_parser = xml_parser_create("UTF-8"); //With UTF8 encoding

//Set parser options
xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, true); //This is a default setting of making all tags uppercase, if set to false you will get the tag name as it's set in the XML.
xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, true); //This should skip values with no values
xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, "UTF-8"); //Set the output as UTF-8

xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "startElement", "endElement");
xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, "characterData");
```

Now you can open the stream....

> $xml->open('http://www.bookingassist.ro/test/HotelsPro.xml');

And you parse the data.
One of the three functions will be triggered depending on whether it's a start tag, end tag or character data.

```
while ($data = read($xml, 4096))
    {
        if (!xml_parse($xml_parser, $data, feof($xml)))     {
            echo "Error in the XML data\t" . xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($xml_parser)));
            break;
    }
```

}

Once the parser is finished, release the resources with....

```
xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
```